# Apache mod rewrite .htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site is a php based site, but I've added wordpress in a /blog/ folder.  The .htaccess file below should allow the /blog/ folder to be accessed, but I get a 404 error saying that blog.php doesn't exist.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1_$2.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anybody able to help at all?

Comment: Do you have WordPress's own .htaccess there?

Comment: no, no other .htaccess at all

Answer (score 1):

The last RewriteRule is redirecting your request to `/blog/` to `index.php`, you should add a `RewriteCond` to check if the request is on the blog folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  My understanding is that the conditionals I've got in there should mean it never gets to the rewrite rule if the file/folder exists.  Obviously this isn't the case, do you know why?

In any case I get the following when using your addition:

[code]The requested URL /blog.php was not found on this server.[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I managed this using the code below, for some reason the conditionals that were suggested don't work (I HATE .htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(blog) - [L]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ /$1_$2.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
RewriteRule ^(blog) - [L]
```

to public_html/.htaccess after

```
RewriteEngine On
```

worked for me as well on a fresh Wordpress installation with Fantastico on a Hostgator account, with a blog.example.com subdomain.